# How to switch between chrome custom tab and webview in android?

Tags: android, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I have implemented both chrome custom tab and webview for a website in android studio. They are both working fine. Now what I want is that if the user doesn't have chrome installed or has a chrome version less than 45 (minimum version needed for chrome custom tab), then open webview class. How to check the chrome version or whether chrome is installed or not? [Here is the code snipet to open chrome custom tab by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vEw7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to bind to the service and if it fails then you can fallback to the webview. You can see it here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/cc6b8b9169ed7e70484bbdbbf39b672d1c4b3c80/Application/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsclient/MainActivity.java#L147

Answer (score 0):

taken from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos/CustomTabActivityHelper.java:

```
public void bindCustomTabsService(Activity activity) {
    if (mClient != null) return;

    String packageName = CustomTabsHelper.getPackageNameToUse(activity);
    if (packageName == null) return;

    mConnection = new ServiceConnection(this);
    CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(activity, packageName, mConnection);
}
```

you can check if 'packageName' is null

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code for my own purpose to check the chrome version with whether chrome is installed or not. Hope it will help, you should try.

```
String chromePackageName = "com.android.chrome";
int chromeTargetVersion  = 45;

boolean isSupportCustomTab = false;

try {
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> list = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (list != null && 0 < list.size()) {
        for (PackageInfo info : list) {
            if (chromePackageName.equals(info.packageName)) {

                String chromeVersion = pm.getPackageInfo(chromePackageName, 0).versionName;
                if(chromeVersion.contains(".")) {
                    chromeVersion = chromeVersion.substring(0, chromeVersion.indexOf('.'));
                }
                isSupportCustomTab = (Integer.valueOf(chromeVersion) >= chromeTargetVersion);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {}

if (isSupportCustomTab) {
    //Use Chrome Custom Tab
} else {
    //Use WebView
}
```